# Was an invisible electrostatic wall generated at a plastic tape factory in August 1980?

Tags: physics, electromagnetism, manufacturing

[Amasci.com](http://amasci.com/weird/unusual/e-wall.html) reported in 1996:

> David Swenson of 3M Corporation describes an anomaly where workers encountered a strange "invisible wall" in the area under a fast-moving sheet of electrically charged polypropelene film in a factory. This "invisible wall" was strong enough to prevent humans from passing through. A person near this "wall" was unable to turn, and so had to walk backwards to retreat from it.

It was also reported by [Wired](https://www.wired.com/story/the-physics-of-plastic-sheets-and-their-invisible-force-fields/) in 2018.

I can find no videos or Mythbusters - in fact no primary sources.

Did this happen?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140601/discussion-on-question-by-qazwsx-was-an-invisible-electrostatic-wall-generated-a).

Answer (score 9):

A primary source for this is [Wide Polypropylene Web Static Charge - A Phenomenon Worthy of “Star Trek”](https://www.google.com/books/edition/SPE_ANTEC_1997_Proceedings/uuBHUl4UNekC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22wide%20polypropylene%20web%20static%20charge%22&pg=PA1310&printsec=frontcover) ANTEC '97 Conference Proceedings, CRC Press, pages 1310-1313.

> A web of polypropylene plastic, 21 feet wide,
> produced for pressure sensitive tape backing in a 3M
> plant, exhibited a unique electrostatic phenomenon. The
> large jumbo roll of film was slit to form conventional
> jumbos 48" to 52" inches wide. As the film was
> unwound on the slitter, the web formed a "tent" of plastic
> 21 feet wide and 20 feet high. Within the tent area, a
> large electrostatic field was produced which formed a
> physical barrier, not unlike a "force-field". Personnel
> could not walk under the "tent" of plastic, at certain
> times of the day, more than half-way without
> experiencing a physical barrier.

This is the drawing on page 1313 depicting the situation:

[image: 20 foot by 21 foot enclosure with one side being the tape splitter and the other next to it being a 12 foot opening]

Comment: Alas, the book can't be reached by the link as the session-cookie/other has run-out. Any chance of adding a quote or two to clarify?

Comment: To me this still is an urban legend as no proof has been given. Even those that spread the story as firsthand state there is no proof to give. From a physics perspective it would seem any field strong enough to repel a human would potentially arch as a human walks through it.

Comment: @JarrodChristman The article says that because of the insulating nature of the floor and and footwear, no discharges occurred.  Also says field was "300kV to 500kV" (per foot I suppose).

Comment: @JiminyCricket I can see the whole article as images.  What Laurel added  is just the abstract.  I don't want to massively plagiarize it.

Comment: How about a paraphrase of the most relevant sections instead of plagiarizing it?

Comment: @JarrodChristman: I agree that this *still* could be some (unfunny) parody, exaggeration or misunderstanding by a relevant, reasonably-widely-published expert. I wouldn't characterise it as an "urban legend" though; we have a published first-person account as a case-study in a journal, not just "it happened to a coworker of a friend" third-hand account.

Comment: `not walk [...] without experiencing a physical barrier` is very different from `had to walk backwards`. When I'd walk through cobwebs, of course I "experience a physical barrier", but I can walk through it :-D